# LINUX-KERNEL: Perf report shared objects showing unknown on ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

There is an issue related to `perf` which I am facing since 15 days. Hoping that the great minds here will help me to solve this.

I have a requirement to make `perf` tool work on a device having ARM architecture. But, on recording the tracepoint events and then running `./perf` report, it shows the shared objects name as `[unknown]` and Symbols as `00000`, whereas for software and hardware events I do not experience this issue.
I have cross compiled the `perf` tool available on mailine and ported it on a device having ARM architecture.

Output on ARM based device with kernel 3.4.

```
./perf record -e kmem:kmalloc cal

[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.007 MB perf.data (~321 samples) ]

./perf report 

Overhead        Command          Shared Object                  Symbol
.......     .............      ..............               ...............
40.78%           cal                [unknown]                [.]00000000
31.6%            cal                [unknown]                [.]00000000

[...]
```

On ubuntu 12.04, system  (kernel 3.10) it works perfectly fine.

Output on x86 architecture

```
./perf record -e kmem:kmalloc gcalctool

[ perf record: Woken up 3 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.27 MB perf.data (~845 samples) ]

./perf report --stdio

Overhead       Command            Shared Object                  Symbol   
...........   .........   ............                  ............
96.55%         cal           [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] kmem_cache_alloc_trace
3.45%          cal           [kernel.kallsyms]            [.]__kmalloc

[...]
```

Keenly, awaiting for you help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe your ARM device? What is the CPU, what is the OS (Linux or Android), ... Have you looked at the "perf report" help? There are options that could be required: --vmlinux and --kallsyms

Comment: Do you have debug symbols on in the kernel?

Comment: Does your kernel .config have CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y?

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply.
my kernel .config has CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y.